# Что такое "малиновый звон"?

Tags: этимология

Здравствуйте!
Думаю, все знают песню в исполнении Гнатюка "Малиновый звон". Я слышал, что это разновидность колокольного звона, но подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за звон и почему он, собственно, малиновый?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словосочетание «малиновый звон» происходит от названия города Мехелен, расположенном  во Фламандском регионе Бельгии (по-французски  Malines - "Малин"), в котором  в Средневековье разработали удачный сплав для литья колоколов. С тех времён на Руси стали так называть красивый, переливающийся звон (сочетание «малиновый звон» имеет значение: «очень приятный, мягкий по тембру звон»).Возможно, в дальнейшем в языке стала прослеживаться связь "малиновый — красный — красивый, прекрасный).

Интересна версия о том, что "малиновый звон" связан с явлением цветного слуха (синтезии), когда два чувства — зрение и слух — связываются воедино. Человек, обладающий цветным слухом, слушая музыку, видит или воображает цветовые зрительные образы.